# Using Signal generator to ouput sine wave to Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project to receive sine wave from signal generator. I want to get output which shows a full sine wave on serial plotter.
Let's say if the input signal is 10hz at 2.0V pk to pk.
I am not getting negative amplitude of the wave in Arduino. I understand that Arduino caps anything below "0V". I have tried using dc offset variable to shift the wave up but all it does is started the wave at the value set for offset and caps the values under that.

```
int gain = 10;
float offset = 2.5;
unsigned long startTime;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Set the start time:
  startTime = millis();
}

void loop() {
  // Check if 20 seconds have passed:
  if (millis() - startTime >= 10000) {
    // Exit the loop after 10 seconds:
    return;
  }
//
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  // Calculate the voltage based on the raw sensor value:
  float voltage = (sensorValue * 5.0 / 1023.0);

  // Apply the AC-coupled amplifier:
  float vout = (voltage - offset) * gain;

  // Shift the signal up and down using an op amp configuration:
  float vout_shifted = (vout * 2.0) - 2.5;

  // Print the voltage amplitude to the serial plotter:
  Serial.print(vout_shifted, 3);
  Serial.println(" V");

  delay(10);
}
```

[image]

*Update*

I am using following setup to sort of using 3.3V DC offset from Arduino
[image]

Updated code*

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}

void loop() {
   // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  //using 3.3V reference to get negative values 
  voltage = voltage - 3.3 ;
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(voltage);
  
  delay(20);
```

}
This has helped to get a full sine wave. I am not too sure if this solution is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The ADC converter on the Arduino can only read from 0-5v (supply voltage), so anything negative is capped. So reading values from 0 to 5v is a physical hardware limitation, and you can't work around it by just subtracting 2.5v from the value afterwards. To put it simply, the value is already being "capped" before the Arduino's CPU sees the value and is able to compute anything with it.

You will have to set the offset the signal electrically. One easy way to do that is setting an offset on the sine wave on the function generator to match this 0-5v range, assuming the function generator supports this option. For example, instead of peak-to-peak 2.0v, you offset it by +2.0v to get a 0-4.0v sine wave.

Comment: I have looked into using DC offset offset cirucit or voltage divider circuit.I have updated the post. Please have a look if the the new way is trivial or not.